# Variable for each element in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Being a rookie at JavaScript, I stumbled upon this simple issue where I need to create an object for each item in an array.

More specifically, I want to create a WYSIWYG text editor for some textareas and then listen to these editor objects for input.

The code for one element would be:

```
// Make an element a text editor area.
var editorArea = new Edicy.TextEditorView({el: $('.foo')});
// Save on input
editorArea.editor.on('aftercommand:composer', function() {
pageData.set('key', 'value');
});
```

As I have many of these areas, I would like to use jQuery.each() to initiate these text editors and according unique listeners, using the data-id attribute of the elements:

```
$('#c-success-tabs-content .tab-pane').each(function(){
    var successID = $(this).attr('data-id');
    successesList.push(successID);
    var editorArea[successID] = new Edicy.TextEditorView({el: $('.foo')});
    editorArea[successID].editor.on('aftercommand:composer', function() {
        pageData.set('key', 'value');
    });
});
```

As the naming scheme "var editorArea[successID]" and from that the listener "editorArea[successID]" are not possible in JavaScript, what would be the optimum solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an object:

```
var editorAreas = {}

$('#c-success-tabs-content .tab-pane').each(function(){
    var successID = $(this).attr('data-id');
    successesList.push(successID);
    editorAreas[successID] = new Edicy.TextEditorView({el: $('.foo')});
    editorAreas[successID].editor.on('aftercommand:composer', function() {
        pageData.set('key', 'value');
    });
});

for(var id in editorAreas){
     console.log(id, editorAreas[id])
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was simpler than expected. I will keep this concept in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Its just your syntax that is wrong; you can have an array of editors

```
var editorArea = [];   // declare globally
```

and then

```
editorArea[successID] = new Edicy.TextEditorView({el: $('.foo')});
```

Comment: Note: declare the `editorArea` variable outside the function scope or you'll just be overwriting it every time.